# Need authentication on OS startup assistance

Tags: boot, authentication

Is it possible to set an authentication on boot-up? If the authentication failed the device will be restarted. Authentication can be anything like system identity, e.g. Mac ID.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by boot-up, but most likely what you want can be done by adding custom entry into systemd.
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ - systemd wiki.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Writing_unit_files - arch wiki entry on systemd.

---

Managed to create service that does something close to what you asked, adding solution.

**Disclamer:** I've implemented and tested this process in Ubuntu MATE 17.04. It should work in 16.04 or above, but there can be problems in older versions. Also worth noting, that systemd was not used in much older versions of Ubuntu either.

### Creating bash script that will perform our auth check by checking if specific USB device is connected.

First of all, we need to create bash script to perform our "auth" check. Here is example of script to perform check based on connected USB device ID:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# test usb auth script
CHECKID="0461:4de3"
READID=$( lsusb -d "$CHECKID" | awk '{print $6}' )
wait
printf "Required: ${CHECKID} \nObtained: ${READID}\n"
if [ "$CHECKID" == "$READID" ]
then
    echo "Usb-auth check passed!"
else
    echo "Usb-auth check failed!"
    echo 'Calling for shutdown...'
    shutdown 0
fi
```

`CHECKID` contains predefined ID of device manufacturer and device itself.
`READID` variable will get result of performing command contained inside `$( )`, in this case it will be `lsusb -d "$CHECKID" | awk '{print $6}'`.
`lsusb -d "$CHECKID"` will try to find device with ID saved in $CHECKID variable, while `awk '{print $6}'` will parse result to save only word number 6 in resulted row. For example `lsusb -d "0461:4de3"` in my system returns this:
`Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0461:4de3 Primax Electronics, Ltd`
and 6th word in this output is exactly device ID.
`wait` call will tell script to wait until any of our previous child commands are done before moving on to comparison.
`printf` is included solely for logging\debugging purposes.
`if [ "$CHECKID" == "$READID" ]` is where actual check is run. In compares `CHECKID` with `READID`, and if they are equal, we have passed check, otherwise we did not and shutdown will be executed.

Step by step process:

**1. Create bash script file.**
Navigate to `/usr/local/bin` while having root privileges (if you are using nautilus\caja, you can open `/usr/local`, right click on "bin" folder and use "open as administrator" option). This folder is used to locate system wide custom scripts. Local user scripts can be created at `/home/[user]/bin` instead. Create empty file and open it with your preferred text editor. Fill it with your check script, as example I will be using USB device check from above:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# test usb auth script
CHECKID="0461:4de3"
READID=$( lsusb -d "$CHECKID" | awk '{print $6}' )
wait
printf "Required: ${CHECKID} \nObtained: ${READID}\n"
if [ "$CHECKID" == "$READID" ]
then
    echo "Usb-auth check passed!"
else
    echo "Usb-auth check failed!"
    echo 'Calling for shutdown...'
    #shutdown 0
fi
```

I used "#" to comment out actual shutdown call, to prevent shutdown during setup and tests.
For the sake of simplicity of example, we will assume that script is named `usb-auth` and full path is `/usr/local/bin/usb-auth`. I will use it in future steps, so make sure to modify them if you use different file name or path.

**2. Give your script executive permissions.**
You can do that by running command `sudo chmod +x [file]`, in my case it will be:
`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/usb-auth`

**3. Find out ID of device you want to use.**

To list usb devices connected to your system you can use command `lsusb`. Connect your USB device, run command, disconnect device, run `lsusb` again, check which device now missing, replace `CHECKID` variable in script with one for your device.
Here is part of my output of this command:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0480:b206 Toshiba America Inc 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0b38:0010 Gear Head 107-Key Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0461:4de3 Primax Electronics, Ltd
```

Device 003 in this case is my mouse, and it will be used in our check, so we will need ID "**0461:4de3**". After we got it, we can store it in our script as base for check, in this line:
    CHECKID="0461:4de3"

**4. Check your script in terminal to make sure it works as intended.**
Make sure that shutdown call is commented out during tests.
Just type name of your script in terminal and it should automatically pick it up, because we located it in ``/usr/local/bin/`.
Checking with device connected:

```
ethuil~$ usb-auth 
Required: 0461:4de3 
Obtained: 0461:4de3
Check passed!
```

Disconnect device, check again:

```
ethuil~$ usb-auth 
Required: 0461:4de3 
Obtained: 
Check failed!
Executing shutdown...
```

After you make sure that script works as intended in running system, we can move to creating service and perform first checks during actual system start-up.

### Creating systemd service to call bash script

**5. Create service file and locate it in /etc/systemd/system/**.
You will need root privileges again for this. Create empty file with extension `.service`, I will name mine `auth-usb.service`.
Open it with your text editor and fill it with content like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=usb-auth bash script
After=network-online.target

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/usb-auth
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

Breaking down this part:

`Description` - this is what you will see in your systemd logs or console during system launch, when systemd will be trying to start this service.

`After` - this property specifies after which service we need to launch our script. In this example we have "network-online.target", which means that our script will be launched only after network will be online. This part can be important if your script uses parts of system affected by other services, for example network connection in this example. You can list all main target services using command:
`systemctl list-units --type=target`
If you are looking for specific service to be up when you run your script, you can list all services using command:
`systemctl list-unit-files`

`WantedBy` - this is important part, which will define at what point our service will be called. Usually custom scripts will be using "WantedBy=multi-user.target" and run after system is started and fully working. In our case we will use "sysinit.target" to make it run during system initialization. If you want to run script at different time, you can use same `systemctl list-units --type=target` as before to list possible values. In my example I will stick to "sysinit.target".

More about [Unit] and [Install] parts:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#%5BUnit%5D%20Section%20Options

`ExecStart` - this is where we tell what exactly we want our service to be running. "/bin/bash" will execute bash interpreter, and "/usr/local/bin/usb-auth" is passed as parameter to tell it location of script to run. If you plan to use not bash script, but actual self made program, you can specify path to your program instead of "/bin/bash *".
`Type=oneshot` - this is type of our service.
`RemainAfterExit=yes` - this part tells that system will consider our service as active even after all its called processes will exit.

More about different types and [Service] part:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=

**6. Enable our newly created service.**
Now that we created our `/etc/systemd/system/auth-usb.service` and `/usr/local/bin/usb-auth` files, we can enable our service by running command `systemctl enable [service filename]`:

```
ethuil~$ systemctl enable auth-usb.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/auth-usb.service → /etc/systemd/system/auth-usb.service.
```

More about `systemctl` command:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#start%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6
**7. Check if our service is working.**
Run command `systemctl restart auth-usb.service` to run our check service.
After you did it, check logs to see if it works as intended using command `journalctl -u auth-usb`.
In my case:

```
ethuil~$ systemctl restart auth-usb.service
ethuil~$ journalctl -u auth-usb
-- Logs begin at Tue 2017-07-25 19:15:23 EEST, end at Tue 2017-07-25 19:15:52 EEST. --
Jul 25 19:15:49 ethuil-300E5Z systemd[1]: Starting usb-auth bash script...
Jul 25 19:15:49 ethuil-300E5Z bash[1262]: Required: 0461:4de3
Jul 25 19:15:49 ethuil-300E5Z bash[1262]: Obtained: 0461:4de3
Jul 25 19:15:49 ethuil-300E5Z bash[1262]: Check passed!
Jul 25 19:15:52 ethuil-300E5Z systemd[1]: Started usb-auth bash script.
```

If there are some issues with script, now is the time to modify it and make sure it works as intended.

**8. Restart system and see if it was launched during system startup as intended.**
Self explanatory. Just restart PC and run `journalctl -u auth-usb` to see if service run as it should. If something is not working the same during startup as during fully running system,  this is way you can check it, by restarting and checking log. You can also run `journalctl -t systemd` to see at which point of system startup your service is getting started and see if you need to change that.

**9. Uncomment "shutdown" command in your script**.
Uncomment part of your script that should be run if check failed and restart system to see if your check script works. This is final check, try running PC with your device connected and without, to see if it works fine. Make sure that you have ways to access script if you wont be able to pass check yourself, for example by having external USB stick with system, from which you can load-up and modify your script.

**10. This is it, we are done. Now you can improve process to fit your personal need.**
At this point you can just modify whole process to fit your needs. Make more complicated bash script or create fully functional program instead, make it to check which USB port you connecting device to, doing something else instead of shutdown (for example silent logging of unauthorized activity instead of just shutting down) etc. In any way, that would be outside of scope of this answer. I did try to make it work with MAC address, and it is possible to do, but my current setup does not have proper and reliable way to test it properly and stable, so I did not include that example.

Comment: thanks for your answer sir but actually i want to set a script which can verify my system mac id only than that device can boot for verifiying mac id i want to keep a file of mac id if in that file mac id is or anything than only device will boot kindly help in this

Comment: I can modify script to work with mac id, but I would need more information about your system and network to do that. It is possible to create script that will compare MAC id instead. If you can update your post with information from `ifconfig` and `ip addr`. By mac id you mean mac address of network device, correct? I also fear that if provided information is not enough for you to do it, you need to learn more about bash scripting first.